# ActionView::MissingTemplate even though template exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a simple login screen. I'd like to return an `:internal_server_error` to my client if there isn't a matching user or if the password is incorrect. However, I'm getting the following missing template error:

> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template login/index,
>   application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json],
>   :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby,
>   :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:   *
>   "C:/Shelf/myGroceryList/app/views"

What has me confused is that I have an `index.html.erb` template in `views/login`. Thoughts?

Route:

```
  post '/login', to: 'login#show'
```

Controller(login_controller.rb):

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def index

  end

  def show
    username = params.values.last["email"]
    password = params.values.last["password"]
    loginType = params.values.last["loginType"]

    if loginType == "Login"
      login(username, password)
    else
      createNewUser(username, password)
    end
  end

  def login(username, password)
    begin
      user = User.find_by(username: username)
      raise(StandardError) if user.password != password
    rescue
      render 'index', :status => :internal_server_error
    end
  end

  def createNewUser(username, password)
    User.new(username: username, password: password)
  end
end
```

View(index.html.erb):

```
<body><%= javascript_pack_tag 'login' %></body>
```

Comment: what i don't understand, is if you are hitting /login which routes to `login#show`, where is it attempting to render the index template?

Comment: Are using API routes?

Comment: @max pleaner, inside the rescue.

Comment: @Pavan, this is more or less a rails api with a react front end. However, I'm not sure the routes are different between rails api and non api. If they are what are those differences?

Answer (score 2):

> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template login/index,
>   application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json],
>   :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby,
>   :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: *
>   "C:/Shelf/myGroceryList/app/views"

The error says it can't find the file with the name **index** and with the format **json**. As are you having an **API**, probably the **request/response** would be in the format **json** not **html**. That said you need to **create** a `index.json.erb` inside `app/views/login` to resolve the error.

Comment: Cool. I'll try this and let you know!